Align Text to 3d Model based on position and normal
I'm attempting to position Text3D snugly on a 3D model in r3f. The user can rotate the model and right-click to place the text. However, I'm struggling with the math to ensure the text appears right-side up and flat on the 3D model based on the position and normal returned from the mouse click.  (so it appears that the 3d text is "on" the surface of the model at the point clicked.  the position is obvious here, but not sure how to calculate the rotation.
This seems like a common challenge in interactive experiences like video games, but I'm unsure where to start with the math. Any guidance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Illustration would help a lot. Basically it looks like you have a Normal from 3D model and an Up vector from the Viewport?
